# UPDATED How do I fix IF/DISPLAY and program math?

Tags: cobol

[UPDATED] I have a program that needs to print the total of column one and column two (WORKING). Then it is suppose to display total of column one divided by the total of column two (.--)(not working). Then display the corresponding letter grade(not working). Then do the same thing for the test section. At the very end display the overall percent (.--) and the corresponding grade.(not working)

Program code:

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
 
       SELECT GRADES-FILE-IN
           ASSIGN TO 'GRADES.SEQ'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
 
       SELECT GRADES-FILE-OUT
           ASSIGN TO 'GRADES.RPT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
 
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  GRADES-FILE-IN.
   01  GRADES-RECORD-IN.
       05  ASG-TEST-ID-IN                 PIC X(14).
       05                                 PIC X.
       05  ACTUAL-POINTS-IN               PIC 9(3).
       05                                 PIC X.
       05  AVAILABLE-POINTS-IN            PIC 9(3).
      
   FD  GRADES-FILE-OUT.
   01  GRADES-RECORD-OUT               PIC X(80).
      
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS       PIC X(3)       VALUE 'YES'.
   01  WS-AVERAGE                   PIC XX.
   01  WS-LETTER                    PIC XX.
   01  WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL              PIC 9(4)       VALUE ZERO.
   01  WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE           PIC 9(4)       VALUE ZERO.
   01  WS-TOTAL-PERCENT             PIC 9V999      VALUE ZERO.
   01  WS-GRAND-TOTAL-ACTUAL        PIC 9(4)       VALUE ZERO.
   01  WS-GRAND-TOTAL-AVAILABLE     PIC 9(4)       VALUE ZERO.
   01  WS-GRAND-TOTAL-PERCENT       PIC 9V99       VALUE ZERO.
   
   01  DETAIL-LINE.
       05  DL-ASG-TEST-ID                  PIC X(14).
       05                                  PIC X(3).
       05  DL-ACTUAL-POINTS                PIC Z,ZZ9.
       05                                  PIC X(3).
       05  DL-AVAILABLE-POINTS             PIC Z,ZZ9.
       
       
       
   01  TOTALS-LINE.
       05                              PIC X(6)       VALUE 'TOTALS'.
       05                              PIC X(11)      VALUE SPACES.
       05  TL-POINTS-ACTUAL            PIC Z,ZZ9.
       05                              PIC X(3)       VALUE SPACES.
       05  TL-POINTS-AVAILABLE         PIC Z,ZZ9.
       05                              PIC X(2)       VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X(7)       VALUE 'Percent'.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE '='.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05  TL-PERCENTAGE               PIC Z.ZZ.
       05                              PIC X(2)       VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X(5)       VALUE 'Grade'.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE '='.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05  TL-LETTER-GRADE             PIC XX.
       
   01  GRAND-TOTALS-LINE.
       05                              PIC X(11)      VALUE 'FINAL GRADE'.
       05                              PIC X(17)      VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X(7)       VALUE 'Percent'.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE '='.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05  GT-PERCENTAGE               PIC Z.ZZ.
       05                              PIC X(2)       VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X(5)       VALUE 'Grade'.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE '='.
       05                              PIC X          VALUE SPACES.
       05  GT-LETTER-GRADE             PIC XX.
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.
       OPEN INPUT GRADES-FILE-IN
       OPEN OUTPUT GRADES-FILE-OUT
       
       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO'
           READ GRADES-FILE-IN
               AT END
                   MOVE 'NO ' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
               NOT AT END
                   PERFORM 200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM
       
       PERFORM 300-PRINT-TOTALS-LINE
       PERFORM 500-PRINT-FINAL-TOTALS-LINE
       
       CLOSE GRADES-FILE-IN
       CLOSE GRADES-FILE-OUT
       STOP RUN.
 
   200-PROCESS-ONE-RECORD.
       IF ASG-TEST-ID-IN = 'Test #1'
           PERFORM 300-PRINT-TOTALS-LINE
       END-IF
       MOVE ASG-TEST-ID-IN TO DL-ASG-TEST-ID    
       MOVE ACTUAL-POINTS-IN TO DL-ACTUAL-POINTS  
       MOVE AVAILABLE-POINTS-IN TO DL-AVAILABLE-POINTS
       MOVE DETAIL-LINE TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT
       WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT.
       COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL = WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL + ACTUAL-POINTS-IN
       COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE = WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE + AVAILABLE-POINTS-IN.
       COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-PERCENT ROUNDED = WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL / WS-GRAND-TOTAL-AVAILABLE.
           
   300-PRINT-TOTALS-LINE.
       MOVE WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL TO TL-POINTS-ACTUAL
       MOVE WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE TO TL-POINTS-AVAILABLE
       MOVE WS-TOTAL-PERCENT TO TL-PERCENTAGE
       MOVE TOTALS-LINE TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT
       WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES
       MOVE SPACES TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT
       WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 3 LINES
       
       ADD WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL TO WS-GRAND-TOTAL-ACTUAL
       ADD WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE TO WS-GRAND-TOTAL-AVAILABLE
       ADD WS-TOTAL-PERCENT TO WS-GRAND-TOTAL-PERCENT
       
       MOVE ZERO TO WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL
       MOVE ZERO TO WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE
       MOVE ZERO TO WS-TOTAL-PERCENT.
       
       
   400-CALCULATE-LETTER.
           
       EVALUATE WS-AVERAGE
       WHEN <= .59
           MOVE 'E' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .66
           MOVE 'D' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .69
           MOVE 'D+' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .72
           MOVE 'C-' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .76
           MOVE 'C' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .79
           MOVE 'C+' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .82
           MOVE 'B-' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .86
           MOVE 'B' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .89
           MOVE 'B+' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN <= .94
           MOVE 'A-' TO WS-LETTER
       WHEN OTHER
           MOVE 'A+' TO WS-LETTER
       END-EVALUATE.

   
   500-PRINT-FINAL-TOTALS-LINE.
       MOVE WS-GRAND-TOTAL-PERCENT TO GT-PERCENTAGE
       MOVE WS-AVERAGE TO GT-LETTER-GRADE
       MOVE GRAND-TOTALS-LINE TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT
       WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT.
```

The current RPT file prints out this:

```
Assignment #1       10      10
Assignment #2       28      30
Assignment #3       45      50
Assignment #4      109     130
Assignment #5       95     100
Assignment #6        0       0
Assignment #7        0       0
Assignment #8        0       0
Assignment #9        0       0
Assignment #10       0       0

TOTALS             287     320  Percent =       Grade =



Test #1              9      12
Test #2             18      18
Test #3             28      37
Test #4             19      25
Test #5             43      55
Test #6             15      23
Test #7              0       0
Test #8              0       0
Test #9              0       0

TOTALS             132     170  Percent =  .41  Grade =



FINAL GRADE                 Percent =  .41     Grade =
```

Needs to print exactly like:

```
Assignment #1       10      10
Assignment #2       28      30
Assignment #3       45      50
Assignment #4      109     130
Assignment #5       95     100
Assignment #6        0       0
Assignment #7        0       0
Assignment #8        0       0
Assignment #9        0       0
Assignment #10       0       0

TOTALS             287     320  Percent =  .90  Grade = B+


Test #1              9      12
Test #2             18      18
Test #3             28      37
Test #4             19      25
Test #5             43      55
Test #6             15      23
Test #7              0       0
Test #8              0       0
Test #9              0       0

TOTALS             132     170  Percent =  .78  Grade = C


FINAL GRADE                     Percent =  .84  Grade = B-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 200-Process... issues

you have

```
   COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL = WS-GRAND-TOTAL-ACTUAL + ACTUAL-POINTS-IN
   COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE = WS-GRAND-TOTAL-AVAILABLE + AVAILABLE-POINTS-IN.
   COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-PERCENT ROUNDED = WS-GRAND-TOTAL-ACTUAL / WS-GRAND-TOTAL-AVAILABLE.
```

it would help is you used the same variable on both sides of the - sign

```
   COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL = WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL + ACTUAL-POINTS-IN
   COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE = WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE + AVAILABLE-POINTS-IN.
   COMPUTE WS-TOTAL-PERCENT ROUNDED = WS-TOTAL-PERCENT ROUNDED / WS-GRAND-TOTAL-AVAILABLE.
```

### 400- issues

it would help adding a few `else` and `end-if` in, Also try moving the value to the output record instead of using a display

Change

```
         IF WS-AVERAGE <= .59
               DISPLAY 'E'
         IF WS-AVERAGE <= .66
```

to

```
           IF WS-AVERAGE <= .59
               move 'E'    to ...
           else
              IF WS-AVERAGE <= .66
                 ...
              else
                 ...
              end-if
           end-if
```

The `evaluate` statement would be much better option though

```
evaluate true
when WS-AVERAGE <= .59
     move 'E'    to ...
when WS-AVERAGE <= .66
     ...
```

---

### Getting the Grade to work

In 300- you need to call 400- and move the grade result to the output record

300-PRINT-TOTALS-LINE.

```
       MOVE WS-TOTAL-ACTUAL TO TL-POINTS-ACTUAL
       MOVE WS-TOTAL-AVAILABLE TO TL-POINTS-AVAILABLE
       MOVE WS-TOTAL-PERCENT TO TL-PERCENTAGE

       perform 400-CALCULATE-LETTER
       move  WS-LETTER              to TL-LETTER-GRADE

       MOVE TOTALS-LINE TO GRADES-RECORD-OUT
       WRITE GRADES-RECORD-OUT AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINES
```

Comment: This helped a bunch, but my averages aren't displaying or are wrong. Also my corresponding letter grade isn't working either. Post has been updated (I edited program code and updated the RPT current output). Thank you for all your past and current help!

Comment: You need to call `400-...` at the start of 300- also move the grade to `TL-LETTER-GRADE` in 400- (or move ts-letter to **TL-LETTER-GRADE** before printing in procedure 300-...)

Comment: I made a new post, can you explain in code over at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450431/how-do-i-fix-displaying-of-student-letter-grade

Comment: I have expanded the answer to include 300- changes. Procedures need to be `performed` other wise they will **not execute**. Output need to be moved to the output record. In programming you have to very precise, computers do exactly what you tell them to do.

Comment: Where has that other post you mentioned gone? Where has the source code of your program in this post gone? Please, stop deleting content, leaving only fragments, once *you* are happy. Others are no longer able to take advantage of this Q&A, which is the intention of this forum.